# sort="asc" Breaks "count" Conditional

Tags: channel-entries

This is super weird. I have this channel entries loop:

```
{exp:channel:entries
  channel='resources_webinars'
  dynamic='no'
  limit='5'
  disable='categores|member_data|pagination'
  orderby='webinars_date'
  sort='asc'
  search:webinars_featured='=not_featured'
}
  {if webinars_date > current_time}

    {if count == 1}
      <div class="heading clearfix">
        <h3>Upcoming Webinars</h3>
      </div><!--/.heading-->

      <ul class="items webinars resetlist">
    {/if}

    <li class="clearfix">
      <article>
        <a href="{webinars_registration}" class="preview">
          <figure>
            {exp:ce_img:single 
              src='{webinars_thumb}' 
              width='210' 
              height='100' 
              crop='yes' 
              allow_scale_larger='yes' 
              alt='{title} preview'
            }
          </figure>
        </a>
        <div class="text clearfix">
          <header>
            <h4><a href="{webinars_registration}">{title}</a></h4>
            <p class="sml"><strong>{webinars_date format='%F %j, %Y'}</strong> / {webinars_date format='%g:%i%A'}</p>
          </header>
          <p>{webinars_summary}</p>
          <footer>
            <a href="{webinars_registration}" class="btn-ui action">Register</a>
          </footer>
        </div><!--/.text-->
      </article>
    </li>

    {if count == total_results}
      </ul>

      {if count == 5}
        <p class="learn-more clearfix"><a href="{path='resources/webinars/upcoming'}">View All Upcoming Webinars &raquo;</a></p>
      {/if}
    {/if}
  {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

It basically shows all non-featured upcoming webinars, sorted by a custom date field. What's weird is that adding `sort="asc"` causes the `{if count}` conditionals at the top and bottom not to work, so the opening and closing `<ul>` tags aren't output.

What's even weirder is that if I put `sort="desc"`, everything works fine.

Anybody ever seen anything like this before?

EE 2.5.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Count is an absolute entry count, so your earlier conditional of {if webinars_date > current_time} may be returning entries that the loop considers "1" but your conditional, run AFTER the returned counted entries, excludes it.  In order to use count, you'd need to narrow the entries loop with a query or a parameter to exclude entries that you don't want returned, or move the {if count == "1"} conditional outside of that wrapping conditional so it fires no matter what.

Comment: An addon that may help you achieve the conditional as a parameter is Solspace's Date Field Filter, which allows you to essentially re-map what the entries loop uses as its date field, and therein you can specify a start date of today, using that newly re-mapped date field.

Comment: Solspace's Date Field Filter is very tempting, but I'm using [DropDate](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dropdate) instead of EE's native date field, and I'd really prefer to keep it.

Comment: I'm thinking [Low Events](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-events) might be a good solution, yeah?

Comment: Date field filter may work on DropDate as well.  It's really kind of like orderby="webinars_date" and then start_date="today".  It doesn't take that form, but that's the idea.

Comment: I haven't tried Low Events yet - depends on how sophisticated your event listing needs are. It's bound to be worth a look though. Everything he does is extremely well thought out.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure it's not your {if webinars_date > current_time} conditional that is skipping entries?